# Filter elements with a regex, only if they are in a certain block

Tags: python, regex, string

In a string (in reality it's much bigger):

```
s = """
BeginA
Qwerty
Element 11 35
EndA

BeginB
Element 12 38
...
Element 198 38
EndB

BeginA
Element 81132 38
SomethingElse
EndA

BeginB
Element 12 39
Element 198 38
EndB
"""
```

how to replace every `Element <anythinghere> 38` which is inside a `BeginB...EndB` block (and only those!) by `Element ABC`?

I was trying with:

```
s = re.sub(r'Element .* 38', 'Element ABC', s)
```

but this doesn't detect if it's in a `BeginB...EndB` block. How to do this?

Comment: Your code is actually working. I don't see how the output is different from what you want.

Comment: @ninesalt I want to replace only the elements which are inside a `BeginB...EndB` block, not those which are in `BeginA...EndA` blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two expressions:

```
block = re.compile(r'BeginB[\s\S]+?EndB')
element = re.compile(r'Element.*?\b38\b')

def repl(match):
    return element.sub('Element ABC', match.group(0))

nstring = block.sub(repl, string)
print(nstring)
```

This yields

```
BeginA
Qwerty
Element 11 35
EndA

BeginB
Element ABC
...
Element ABC
EndB

BeginA
Element 81132 38
SomethingElse
EndA

BeginB
Element 12 39
Element ABC
EndB
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/3PJrjF).

---

Without `re.compile` (just to get the idea):

```
def repl(match):
    return re.sub(r'Element.*?\b38\b', 'Element ABC', match.group(0))

print re.sub(r'BeginB[\s\S]+?EndB', repl, s)
```

The important idea here is the fact that [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)'s second parameter **can be a function**.

---

You could very well do it without a function but you'd need the newer `regex` module which supports `\G` and `\K`:

```
rx = re.compile(r'''
    (?:\G(?!\A)|BeginB)
    (?:(?!EndB)[\s\S])+?\K
    Element.+?\b38\b''', re.VERBOSE)

string = rx.sub('Element ABC', string)
print(string)
```

See another [**demo for this one on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/pxS2Bk/1) as well.

Comment: Wonderful, I forgot that we could use *a function* as the second parameter of `re.sub`! I edited your answer to add these details, I hope you don't mind @Jan.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
r'(?s)(?<=BeginB)\s+Element\s+(\d+)\s+\d+.*?(?=EndB)'
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/22fWif/1/).

For your example, I would echo @Jan's answer and use two separate regular expressions:

```
import re

restrict = re.compile(r'(?s)(?<=BeginB).*?(?=EndB)')
pattern = re.compile(r'Element\s+(\d+)\s+38')

def repl(block):

    return pattern.sub('Element ABC', block.group(0))

out = restrict.sub(repl, s)
```

Comment: How do you do the replace? `s = re.sub(r'(?s)(?<=BeginB)\s+Element\s+(\d+)\s+\d+.*?(?=EndB)', r'Element ABC', s)` doesn't work directly, so I guess we should modify the replacement string `r'Element ABC'`, how?

Comment: To clarify, from your example, you would want to replace `12`, `198` and `12` again correct?

Comment: Yes indeed. All the lines inside a BeginB...EndB block which are of the form `Element .... 38`. IRL I have a few (but not many) BeginB...EndB blocks, thousands of elements inside them, and other blocks BeginA...EndA, BeginC...EndC, etc.